# Excel Userform Listview Colour individual grids (cells)

Tags: excel, listview, userform, vba

I have a listview control on an Excel userform. I have set the gridlines to true. I want it to represent the Excel sheet as much as possible, including cell formatting. All I want to do is fill individual listview grids with the same colour as that on the Excel sheet. Is this possible?

I've seen solutions for entire listview rows and I've noticed that VB.NET listviews have a 'backcolor' property but I'm not sure if this is possible within Excel VBA. I can change the forecolor, which changes the font color in particular cells.

Comment: Presumably you are using the Common Controls ListView component, this does not support background colours for subitems.  You can use a dynamic background image to colour an entire column but thats about it (without getting in to custom drawing).  Looking for a 3rd party grid component may be an option.

Comment: Yes I am, I only discovered it the other day but I'm surprised at how little information there is out there about how to use it. 3rd part grid component looks like a good option. Thanks!